# Why doesn't me image redraw after clear?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

After clearing I want to redraw my images (now it's just static but it will be animated in the future). It draws one time and after clears it but never redraws the images, why is this?

```
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var width = 640;
var height = 145;

var width2 = 640;
var height2 = 145;

startInterval();

function startInterval() {
  setInterval(function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 640, 145);

    var text = new Image();
    var background = new Image();
    text.src = "../assets/img/title.svg";
    background.src = "../assets/img/mask.png";

    text.onload = function() {
      background.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(text, 0, 0);
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, width, height);
        console.log("Drew image");
      };
    }
  }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are never resetting the [`globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) property of your context.

And since `source-in` will draw only new pixels that are positioned over existing non-transparent pixels, if you context is all clear, you won't add any new pixel.

To fix it, set your gCO to the default `source-over` once you're done with your compositing.

---

Now, I can't let you use such a code...

Do not nest load events like that, you want both to fire, and you are lucky you have this setInterval, otherwise you may well have your background's event fire before you attached the handler to it.

And do not reset your images `src` like that either.

Instead, load your assets once, wait that all the assets are loaded, and only then start the routine/drawing.

```js
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

var toLoad = 2; // how many assets are we waiting for
var assetsLoaded = 0; // a counter
var text = new Image();
var background = new Image();
// set the same handler for both Images
text.onload = background.onload = onassetload;
text.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png';
background.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg';

function onassetload() {
 assetsLoaded = assetsLoaded + 1; // udpate our counter
 if(assetsLoaded >= toLoad) { // all assets are ready
   startInterval();
 }
}
function startInterval() {
  c.width = text.width;
  c.height = text.height;
  setInterval(draw, 2000);
  draw();
function draw(){
    // here we just draw, no Image loading anymore
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.drawImage(text, 0, 0);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
    // reset the gCO to its default
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    console.log("Drew image");
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```